# Subresultants of primitive polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Given two primitive polynomials $f,g\in D[x]$ over some domain $D$, is there anything we can say about the primitiveness of their $i$-th subresultant polynomials $Sres_i(f,g)$? I.e. is there a simple way to determine the content of $Sres_i(f,g)$, and in particular is it always 1?

Comment: I'm familiar with the resultant of two polynomials, but not with subresultants. Can you meet us halfway?